# Group one column by another column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I would like to get the median value of one column and use the associated value of another column. For example,

```
   col1  col2 index
0     1     3     A
1     2     4     A
2     3     5     A
3     4     6     B
4     5     7     B
5     6     8     B
6     7     9     B
```

I group by the index to get the median value of col 1, and use the associated value of col 2 to get

```
   col1  col2 index
    2     4     A
    5     7     B
```

I can't use the actual median value for index B because it will average the two middle values and that value won't have a corresponding value in col 2. 
What's the best way to do this? Will a groupby method work? Or somehow use sort? Do I need to define my own function?

Comment: Seems like not even you know what you want? For `index` A it is pretty easy to do, just `df.groupby('index').median()` but what about for `index` B? Why did you choose `5` and not `6`?

Comment: When this case happen , why you did not pick up 6 8 for B

Comment: For B, either 5 or 6 is acceptable to me. But I can't use 5.5 because there isn't an associated value in the other column.

Comment: Using `df.groupby('index').median()` would yield both col 1 and col 2 as median values, instead of col 2 corresponding to the median value of col 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need take middle position not `median` from origial df

```
df.groupby('index')[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(sorted(x.values.tolist())[len(x)//2]))
Out[297]: 
       0  1
index      
A      2  4
B      6  8
```

Comment: This works. I just have to shift back to a dataframe afterward and rename the columns. Can you explain how it only sorts by `col 1` when `[['col1','col2']]` are in the statement?